# mysql query help - REPLACE INTO?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `PHP file` that reads in a CSV file and stores the values into an SQL table.

The SQL table has 4 columns

```
 id - primary key (just auto incremented integer)
 name - text value of an object name
 type - an integer value representing the type of object
 active - a bool to set if the object is active
```

The problem is the `CSV file` doesn't store the id, just the name and type.

I want to do the following and wondered what the best way to do this is with the least amount of queries.

set `active to 0` for every entry in the table

```
For each entry in the CSV
if (name and type already exists in table)
  set active to 1 
else 
   add new entry to the table

return the id for the existing or new entry
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

- just a note, it's just the mysql queries i'm after, not php code etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL 'UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY' without a unique column?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3180913/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using mysql:

First you have to create "unique" index on 2 fields: `name` and `type` (it's one index not two)

Then insert your data using this query:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`name`,`type`,`active`) VALUES ($name,$type,0)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active = 1
```

In order to get ID you just query it (the smart way - mysql_insert_id() doesn't work with INSERT UPDATE)

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE `name`= '$name' AND `type` = '$type'
```

Comment: hi izeed, thanks alot, I didn't realise I could create a unique key with more than one value.